# How to Count Unique squares a robot visits in C# console

Tags: c#

You work for a company that sells robots that move around a factory floor in a grid like pattern. Your boss has asked you to write a program that will test how many unique squares a robot visits given a set of instructions.
For example the input N4,E2,S2,W4 (described below) should result in a value of 11.
The robot starts at position 1, heads north for four blocks, east for two blocks, south for two and west for four. During those steps it visits blocks 1-12 once except for block 2 which it visits twice. Block 2 should only be counted once. The size of the grid is unknown and not given in the input.
I have tried the below but is not getting unique values.I also want a way to get the input in the formart N4,E2,S2,W4 not with separate prompts for direction.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x1 = 0;
    int y1 = 0;

    int x2 = 0;
    int y2 = 0;

    int x3 = 0;
    int y3 = 0;

    int x4 = 0;
    int y4 = 0;



    int N, S, E, W, Total;
    string coordinate1, coordinate2, coordinate3, coordinate4;


    Console.Write("Enter North : ");
    N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if(N != 0)
    {
        x1 += 0;
        y1 += N;

    }
    coordinate1 = "(" + x1 + "," + y1 + ")";








    Console.Write("Enter East: ");
    E = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (E != 0)
    {
        y3 += 0;
        x3 += E;

    }
    coordinate3 = "(" + x3 + "," + y3 + ")";



    Console.Write("Enter South: ");
    S = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (S != 0)
    {
        x2 += 0;
        y2 -= S;

    }

    coordinate2 = "(" + x2 + "," + y2 + ")";


    Console.Write("Enter West: ");
    W = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (W != 0)
    {
        y4 += 0;
        x4 -= W;

    }
    coordinate4 = "(" + x4 + "," + y4 + ")";




    if (coordinate1 == coordinate2|| coordinate1== coordinate3 || coordinate1 == coordinate4 || coordinate2 == coordinate3 || coordinate2 == coordinate4 || coordinate3 ==coordinate4 )
    {
        Total = (N + S + E + W) - 1 ;
        Console.WriteLine("The total Blocks travelled are " + Total);
    }

    else
    {
        Total = N + S + E + W;
        Console.WriteLine("The total Blocks travelled are " + Total);
    }



}
```

Comment: We aren't going to do your homework for you. Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have added the sample code of what i have tried please help.

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, I work for a company that sells tailor made software solutions, but working with robots sounds like a lot of fun.

Comment: Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Are you *sure* you get Nx,Ex,Sx,Wx in that exact order? My *guess* would be that you could get any path (comma separated, letter for direction followed by distance).

Comment: Start at coordinate (0,0) and maintain a list of locations visited. For every step (and "N4" is 4 steps), see if you have visited that location previously. Count accordingly

Comment: @Hans,yes the order can vary but it will always be 4 compass direction,can you demonstrate your suggestion  by modifying  my code snippet?

Comment: BTW, don't limit the path to a fixed four directions. A path might very well be `S3,N2` or `N3,E5,S4,W3,N7,S2,W1` - In the software industry you should never expect the users to work with the software as they should.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly a homework exercise so I will not provide any code in this answer, only an explanation on how to approach it.

So, since the floor is a grid with unknown size, you must assume an infinite graph where your robot starts at (0,0):

```
       N
       |
       |
W------+------E
       |
       |
       S
```

Now, each step the robot takes in each direction it lends on a point in the graph - say the instructions are N4 - you add the points (1,0), (2,0), (3,0),(4,0) to your already existing (0,0) point. Then you move E2 - add (4,1) and (4,2) to the collection of points. Next S5 so you add (3,2), (2,2) (1, 2), (0, 2), (-1, 2) to the collection and so on. Each direction only changes one coordinate. Then all you have to do is count the number of the distinct coordinates and you're done.

Hint: For this exercise you might want to only collect the distinct points (you can use a `HashSet` for this), but when designing a software you must think beyond current requirements since customers rarely know what they want and even more what they actually need. In this case, you better collect all the points even if they are duplicates and even if this is not needed for this specific task, because the next exercise might very well be to recreate the instruction based on the robot's path, and for that it would be easier to rebuild it from the full set of coordinates. On that note, you would want to save the points in a collection that provides index based access like a `List`.

Comment: Thanks Zohar, even if it  is a homework,Can you show me as code example I am not proficient in C# i am still learning.

Comment: I can but if I do that you will not learn. There is only one way of learning how to do something and that's to do it yourself. Give it a try, if you get stuck somewhere come back and ask a new, more specific question. chances are someone will answer it.

Comment: @user3755374 start with reading a single command string ("N4,E31"). Then use String.Split to get separate commands. Print them ("N4", "E31"). Next step: decode the commands and print them as "North, 4 steps" (etc). Next step: print all locations you visit, assuming you start from (0,0) - "N4" visits 4 locations! Don't try and create the final solution at once, split the problem into small steps that you *can* solve and slowly build towards the solution.

Comment: i understand,so if i enter N4, how must i add this points (1,0), (2,0), (3,0),(4,0)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Conventionally, in geography, the `N` is facing up and `E` is facing left - and in Math, when you draw a graph, the `Y` is facing up and `X` is facing left - so `(1,0)` is `Y1, X0` or `N1, E0`.